# Passwordless SMS authentification - Token expiration & Security

Tags: security, authentication, twilio, sms, token

I am looking to implement a passwordless solution for a mobile app currently in production. The aim is to make the login process smoother for the users by removing the use of a password. Since the app is mobile only and that the phone number of the users is already used as a username I feel like a solution using Twilio to generate an OTP (one-time-password) to login is a good alternative.

Nonetheless today when a user logs in, the authentication token has no expiration date (he stay logged in forever). I would like to know if using an OTP to generate such unlimited (or very long lasting) auth token would be considered as a security issue. Is there some best practice to take into consideration like refresh tokens or other ...

To be clear my question is:

Is using OTP with SMS considered as a good practice to stay always logged in to an app ? And do you see any flaw in my reasoning ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look https://bere.al/en , Bereal use this system to auth users.
We have probleme when you change/lose you sim card.
But I don't see any security problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look. For the SIM card loss it could be a good idea to give the possibility to connect with an OTP generate by email (with the verified email of the account for example)